# Bounded operators that are not closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If a bounded operator, say $A:D(A)\to X$, have $D(A)=X$ then it is closed.

Can anybody construct an example of a bounded linear operator, without resorting and restricting to $D(A)=X$, that is not closed?

Please give the examples including densely defined operators,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Actually that equivalence holds only if the codomain is complete. Moreover that extension also only exists if the codomain is complete.

Comment: @Freeze_S : Yes, I retract that remark.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Well the problem is that most of the results really only hold for both the ambient spaces being Banach spaces even for the target space - except that little exception "closed domain operator bounded implies operator closed"...

Answer (score 6):

If $A : \mathcal{D}(A) \subseteq X\rightarrow X$ is a bounded linear operator on a Banach space $X$, then $A$ is closed iff $\mathcal{D}(A)$ is closed. So, for the case where $X$ is complete, the only example of a non-closed bounded operator $A : \mathcal{D}(A)\subseteq X\rightarrow X$ is the restriction of a bounded operator to a non-closed subspace $\mathcal{D}(A)$ of $X$. Any non-closed subspace $\mathcal{D}(A)$ and any $A \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ will work to produce a non-closed $A : \mathcal{D}(A)\subset X\rightarrow X$.

For the case of an incomplete normed linear space $X$, and bounded densely-defined $A : \mathcal{D}(A)\subseteq X\rightarrow X$, some things can be said by densely and isometrically embedding $X$ in its completion $\hat{X}$, and then uniquely extending $A$ to a continuous linear operator $\hat{A} : \hat{X}\rightarrow \hat{X}$. The problem now looks like that of the previous paragraph, but is more difficult to characterize in terms of $X$ alone. However, if you start with a bounded $\hat{A} : \hat{X}\rightarrow\hat{X}$ on a Banach space $\hat{X}$, then an example is produced on some dense non-closed subspace $X$ providing (a) $X$ can be found such that $\hat{A}X \subseteq X$ and (b) a subspace $\mathcal{D}(A)\subset X$ can be found which is dense in $X$ but not closed in $X$ (all topologies are inherited from that of $\hat{X}$.)

Comment: Sorry for replying to this old post, but I've just came across a similar question. Am I missing something or does it more generally hold that if $A$ is a bounded linear operator between two normed vector spaces $E_1$ and $E_2$, then it always holds "$\mathcal D(A)$ is closed $\Rightarrow$ $A$ is closed". And if $E_2$ is complete, then the other direction holds as well. If you agree with that, is the completeness assumption in the latter direction necessary? I wasn't able to prove the claim without it.

Answer (score 1):

A (probably to) simple example is $T:D\to X:x\mapsto 0$ for some unclosed dense $D\subsetneq\overline{D}=X$. There $T$ is bounded densely defined but not closed, however, closable.

A more sophisticated bounded nonclosable example would require a little more work since one needs to consider an incomplete space and a nice fitted operator since:

*"A bounded operator $T:D\to Y$ with $D\subseteq X$ and $X$ not necessarily complete but $Y$ complete extends to a bounded operator $T_E:\overline{D}\to Y$ that is indeed closed."*

Comment: A bounded $T : D \subsetneq X\rightarrow X$ on a normed space $X$ is closable because the closure of its graph in $X\times X$ is still a graph as it cannot include $(0,y)$ unless $y=0$.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Oh good point! :) So but then the domain of its closure is not necessarily the closure of the domain of itself?

Comment: That sounds correct.

Comment: @C-Star-Puppy: "A bounded operator T:D→Y with D⊆X and X not necessarily complete but Y complete, extends to a bounded operator TE:D→Y
 that is indeed closed." I couldn't find a reference with such a theorem. Could you suggest where I could find it, or how this statement could be proven?

Comment: @Sanket_Diwale: Bounded, i.e. continuous, operators extend continuously to the completion (assuming that the target is complete), and a bounded operator is always closed, i.e. has a closed graph. The first statement and its proof can be found for example in Kreyszig, while the second is so trivial that it doesn't even require a mention, but probably you can find this in Kreyszig, too. Hope this helps ;)