# Is any bounded operator weakly sequentially closed?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have a theorem telling me that some property holds for operators that are bounded and weakly sequentially closed. Somehow, I have in mind that boundedness actually implies the weakly sequentially closedness. My reasoning would be this: As boundedness implies closedness and since convex sets (graph is convex) are weakly sequentially closed if they are closed, the second property should be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

A bounded operator is closed if and only if its domain is, so your implication "boundedness implies closedness" is not true in general.
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954105/bounded-operators-that-are-not-closed) for more details.

Comment: In this case I think OP is taking bounded operators defined on the entire space.

Comment: Maybe. If this is the case, I will delete. I'll wait for OP to tell us.